# Use bcrypt password hashing with OpenLDAP (slapd)

Tags: openldap, password, slapd, bcrypt

I have an OpenLDAP LDAP server on Debian 9 (through the slapd package, v2.4.44). We use crypt for password authentication. Currently the scheme is SHA512: `$5$...`.
The setup is pretty much as described in this question: [How to use SHA-256 hashed (and salted) passwords from OpenLDAP in pam_ldap?](https://serverfault.com/questions/734906/how-to-use-sha-256-hashed-and-salted-passwords-from-openldap-in-pam-ldap) (and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C))

I was thinking I would try to upgrade from SHA512 to bcrypt (blowfish hashes, `$2y$...`) since they are much harder to crack.

The beauty about the crypt back-end is the scheme is saved in the password itself. So to test bcrypt I can just log into my LDAP browser and change my own password to `{CRYPT}$2y$10$...$`, using an online tool to produce the hash.

However, if I now try to login with that account, it says my credentials are invalid.

For the record, with the process described I can successfully change the hash to other types and still login. It seems that bcrypt specifically is not recognized, but I expect the option to be there.

So, what else do I need to do to let OpenLDAP work with bcrypt?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. It seems the shipped version of `libcrypt` simply does not support bcrypt.

Following [this blog from 2019](https://blog.drylm.org/posts/openldap_blowfish/), I downloaded and build an extension to `libcrypt` that does include bcrypt (and is backwards compatible)

I'll copy the steps in case the blog disappears:

- Clone or download the `libxcrypt` library: https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt (I got [version 4.4.3](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/archive/v4.4.3.tar.gz))
- Build the source with:
  `$ ./bootstrap && ./configure && make`

  - You might require the packages `autoconf`, `automake`, `libtool` and `pkg-config` (see the repo Readme for further instructions)
- Install the freshly compiled `libcrypt`:
  `$ cp ./.libs/libcrypt.so.1.1.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
- Backup the old `libcrypt`:
  `$ cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu && cp libcrypt.so.1 libcrypt.so.1.0.0`
- And now replace `libcrypt` with a link to the new version:
  `$ rm libcrypt.so.1 && ln -s libcrypt.so.1.1.0 libcrypt.so.1`

**Warning:** With `libcrypt` missing or corrupt, your system cannot perform any authentications! Including logins and `sudo ...` commands. So make sure to replace the file in one go and be prepared for a complete lock-out

With these changes `{CRYPT}$2y$...` hashes are accepted!
I use the PHP [crypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function to create new password hashes.

Comment: Just noticed that on the Wikipedia page it's mentioned that on Linux `libcrypt` does not support bcrypt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Support_in_operating_systems, so I could have seen this coming. Maybe on Debian 10 it's supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial bcrypt module for OpenLDAP at https://github.com/wclarie/openldap-bcrypt/

However I would strongly advise instead using an OpenLDAP build that includes support for Argon2 password hashes.